# In C++, how do I add an argument to an "Args&&... args" list of arguments?

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic-functions

I have my own thread implementation which allows me to manage various ways of communicating with my threads. It is based on the C++ `std::thread` class.

I create the thread to run a function named `run()` which calls the user function. What I'd like to be able to do is call the user function including my thread object pointer.

There is where I have a problem in the constructor. I want to pass the `Args` as specified on the constructor and prepend `this` to that list:

```
class safe_thread
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<safe_thread>    pointer_t;
    typedef std::vector<pointer_t>          vector_t;

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    safe_thread(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
        : f_function([this, f, args...]{ std::bind(f, this, args...)(); })
    {
[...snip...]

private:
    std::function<void()>               f_function;
};

// I use that constructor with two different types of signatures:
//
// 1. member function
//
safe_thread listen(&my_other_class::some_function, this);

// 2. static function
//
safe_thread worker(&my_static_function);
```

`std::bind()` does not understand my current syntax. It expects a function (`f`) and `args...`. So, how do I *change* `args...` to include `this`?

Comment: Why use `bind` at all here?  `f(this, args...);` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Also, even with the bind the syntax seems correct. Are you sure you're passing the right amount of arguments?

Comment: @MilesBudnek, if I call `safe_thread` with an `std::bind()` because I want to call a member function, a direct `f(...)` fails with _error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’_

Comment: So `f` is a pointer-to-member-function of `safe_thread` (you're trying to bind it to pass `this` [a `safe_thread*`] as the first argument)? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: `(this->*f)(args...)` ?

Comment: as usual providing MCVE might help.

Comment: If you want the first _user supplied_ argument to be used as the `this` pointer for a pointer-to-member-function supplied for `f` then you'll likely need to do some template specialization or SFINAE gymnastics.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, yeah, I'm realizing now that I have a parent `this` and the `safe_thread this`... and I'm passing them in the wrong order.

Comment: If `f` is a member function pointer whose `this` is already supplied in `args...`, injecting a different `this` before `args...` is going to fail.  Basically there are enough wrong things in the above code and misunderstandings (by you) about what is going wrong that you **need** a [MCVE].  The errors you get when you screw up bind or similar operations are opaque, so I simply do *not* trust you when you describe what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I actually found a solution which is to move the `this` parameter to the end of the list. This way my `std::invoke()` to a member function or a standard static function work alike:

```
f_function([this, f, args...]{ std::invoke(f, args..., this)(); })
```

Without that, as mentioned by Miles Budnek, a load of SFINAE would be required to know whether `f` is a member function or a plain function.

The problem was that in some cases I would create a thread in a member function and in other cases I would create a tread out of a static function.

In case of the member function, the first argument in the `args...` list is the caller's `this` and obviously that `this` can't be moved over as the next parameter.

In effect, my first attempt was generating this:

```
std::invoke(
    &my_other_class::some_func,     // correct
    safe_thread::this,              // wrong 'this' (i.e. safe_thread)
    my_other_class::this,           // 'this' for function, wrong location
    ...);                           // other parameters
```

By changing the order in my call, I now get the correct 'this' at the correct location:

```
std::invoke(
    &my_other_class::some_func,     // correct
    my_other_class::this,           // 'this' for function, correct location
    ...,                            // other parameters
    safe_thread::this);             // 'this' to safe_thread
```

Obviously this means I have to fix the signature of the called functions, but I'm fine with that.

---

As mentioned by tkausl, `std::bind()` is not required. See comments for details about that. That being said, `std::invoke()` is C++17, so if you're still on an older version, you'll probably have to stick to `std::bind()`.

Comment: Whats the point of `std::bind`? You can call `std::invoke` directly.

Comment: Good point. At first I was thinking to save the binding in `f_function`, but I could not see how to determine the type in the class without making my class a template (the return type depends on the input parameters). So yes, `std::invoke()` works just fine. I'll update my answer with that.